# Using dtrace in objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, dtrace, network-traffic

I use dtrace with parameters below to calculate a specific process network traffic usage :

```
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::recvfrom:return { @[pid] = sum(arg0); }'
```

How could I use dtrace in objective C?

I used `NSTask` to launch dtrace with above parameters but as results of this dtrace command shows up after terminating dtrace, I couldn't see the results unless terminating dtrace. As dtrace stays in a loop for calculating traffic of given process and because of using of NSPipe I could't be able to use `[task terminate]` command. So my main question is:

How to use dtrace in objective C with `NSTask` or without it (via another method) and terminating it properly and then seeing results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour is not to print out anything, but you can put in a profile kicker to get it to print the output at an interval. Adding a clause like:

```
profile:::tick-1sec
{
  printa(@);
}
```

should achieve the desired effect.

or, as using your `sudo` call:

```
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::recvfrom:return { @[pid] = sum(arg0); } profile:::tick-1sec { printa(@); }'
```

Comment: It doesn't work for NSTask and still I couldn't see the results through pipe.

Comment: I found a solution for my problem with help of above answer . For getting result through pipe , we should use [file availableData].